# Not able to import Spark Implicits in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, implicit, scalatest

I am writing Test Cases for Spark using ScalaTest.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FlatSpec}

class ClassNameSpec extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  var spark: SparkSession = _
  var className: ClassName = _

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("class-name-test").getOrCreate()
    className = new ClassName(spark)
  }

  it should "return data" in {
    import spark.implicits._
    val result = className.getData(input)

    assert(result.count() == 3)
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

When I try to compile the test suite it gives me following error:

```
stable identifier required, but ClassNameSpec.this.spark.implicits found.
[error]     import spark.implicits._
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I am not able to understand why I cannot `import spark.implicits._` in a test suite.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Its because you have defined `SparkSession` as `var`. Defining it as `val` or `transforming` to a `val` should work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To do an import you need a "stable identifier" as the error message says. This means that you need to have a val, not a var.
Since you defined spark as a var, scala can't import correctly.

To solve this you can simply do something like:

```
val spark2 = spark
import spark2.implicits._
```

or instead change the original var to val, e.g.:

```
lazy val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("class-name-test").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked for me ! But it is strange to know that `SparkSession` behaves weirdly when defined as `var`. Do you know the reason behind it ?

Comment: it has nothing to do with SparkSession. SparkSession behaves perfectly normal. It is an issue with importing. Import requires a stable identifier. A stable identifier can be a val but not a var or def

Comment: Oh...Ok! Didn't knew that :)